# Perceptron problems

Tags: python, machine-learning, perceptron

I am trying to make a training set of data points by making a line (perceptron) f and making the points on one side +1 and -1 on the other. Then making a new line g and trying to get it as close to f as possible by updating with w = w+ y(t)x(t) where w is weights and y(t) is +1,-1 and x(t) is coordinates of a missclassified point. after implementing this tho i am not getting a very good fit from g to f. here is my code and some sample outputs.

```
import random

random.seed()

points = [ [1, random.randint(-25, 25), random.randint(-25,25), 0] for k in range(1000)]

weights = [.1,.1,.1]

misclassified = []

############################################################# Function f

interceptf = (0,random.randint(-5,5))

slopef = (random.randint(-10, 10),random.randint(-10,10))

point1f = ((interceptf[0] + slopef[0]),(interceptf[1] + slopef[1]))
point2f = ((interceptf[0] - slopef[0]),(interceptf[1] - slopef[1]))

############################################################# Function G starting
interceptg = (-weights[0],weights[2])

slopeg = (-weights[1],weights[2])

point1g = ((interceptg[0] + slopeg[0]),(interceptg[1] + slopeg[1]))
point2g = ((interceptg[0] - slopeg[0]),(interceptg[1] - slopeg[1]))
#############################################################

def isLeft(a, b, c):
      return ((b[0] - a[0])*(c[1] - a[1]) - (b[1] - a[1])*(c[0] - a[0])) > 0


for i in points:
    if isLeft(point1f,point2f,i):
        i[3]=1
    else:
        i[3]=-1

for i in points:
    if (isLeft(point1g,point2g,i)) and (i[3] == -1):
        misclassified.append(i)

    if (not isLeft(point1g,point2g,i)) and (i[3] == 1):
        misclassified.append(i)

print len(misclassified)


while misclassified:
    first = misclassified[0]
    misclassified.pop(0)

    a = [first[0],first[1],first[2]]
    b = first[3]

    a[:] = [x*b for x in a]

    weights = [(x + y) for x, y in zip(weights,a)]

interceptg = (-weights[0],weights[2])

slopeg = (-weights[1],weights[2])

point1g = ((interceptg[0] + slopeg[0]),(interceptg[1] + slopeg[1]))
point2g = ((interceptg[0] - slopeg[0]),(interceptg[1] - slopeg[1]))

check = 0

for i in points:
    if (isLeft(point1g,point2g,i)) and (i[3] == -1):
        check += 1

    if (not isLeft(point1g,point2g,i)) and (i[3] == 1):
        check += 1

print weights
print check
```

117 <--- number of original missclassifieds with g

[-116.9, -300.9, 190.1] <--- final weights

617 <--- number of original missclassifieds with g after algorithm

956 <--- number of original missclassifieds with g

[-33.9, -12769.9, -572.9] <--- final weights

461 <--- number of original missclassifieds with g after algorithm

Answer (score 0):

There are at least few problems with your algorithm:

- Your "while" conditions is wrong - the perceptron learning is not about iterating **once** through all **misclassified** points as you do now. The algorithm should iterate through **all the points** for as long as **any of them** is missclassified. In particular - each update can make some correctly classified point as the wrong one, so you have to always iterate through **all of them** and check if everything is fine.
- I am pretty sure that what you actually wanted is update rule in form of `(y(i)-p(i))x(i)` where `p(i)` is predicted label and `y(i)` is a true label (but this obviously degenrates to your method if you only update misclassifieds)